# sql query condition on temporary column

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, temp-tables

I pondered on this one a little bit. Found a few question on SO but none of them addressed my problem.

What I am trying to do is compare two dates in a table, I am returning the greater of the two using a case statement

```
select <-- similar code but not actual code
...
case
when date1 > date2 then date1 else date2 end as lastDate
```

Everything fine upto this point. I get the greater date in my result. The problem is I want to apply a WHERE clause on LastDate. Since the lastDate is a temporary column, it won't be accept in WHERE clause I came up with this syntax

```
if @cur_date != null  <---- this is parameter to my store procedure, if not null then
case when date1 > date then date1 like '2011-%' else date2 like '2011-%'
```

But I get an error for the misplaced 'like' keyword. I think a statement can not be returned after the 'then' keyword in case statement. How do I do this? Do I *have* to use temporary table for this? I want to find the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your same syntax in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE case when date1 > date2 then date1 
      else date2 END
      like '2011-%'
```

**EDIT:**

Sample code for Date comparison:

```
WHERE case when date1 > date2 then CAST(date1 as varchar)
      else CAST(date2 as varchar) END
      like '2011-%'
```

Comment: great, Now the only other problem I have is if I search `like '%2011-05%`, it does not return any record. I want it to return records that has '2011-05' in it, Do you know why that is so and what will be correct query in this case?

Comment: If you are comparing to a `datetime` or `smalldatetime` field, you can't use `LIKE`.  You need to either do evaluation with `DATEPART`, or `CONVERT` to a string like `varchar` then use `LIKE`